# Trouble running openai gym environment on google colab

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

[Error that I'm struggling with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZYix.png)

I'm trying to use MarsExplorer (https://github.com/dimikout3/MarsExplorer) in google colab, but I'm struggling with properly importing it. I was able to successfully clone the repo, but when I try to run the demo mars_explorer isn't imported. How can I fix this?

Comment: Cloning a repo is not enough, you need to install the library.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed @Dr.Snoopy makes a great point here. This is the line in `test.py` where it is expected to work:

`from mars_explorer.envs.settings import DEFAULT_CONFIG as conf`

Now, notice that this is being called from your runtime path, usually root in Colab's case (I suppose), then it should return an error.

Now, if installed, for instance with `pip install -e` you can both import the module and edit it as you go.

Check out these [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#:%7E:text=a%20test%20suite).-,6.1.2.%20The%20Module%20Search%20Path,-%C2%B6), they may be helpful to understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

apply these two commands in  colab cell:

1. !git clone https://github.com/dimikout3/GeneralExplorationPolicy.git

the above command will save GeneralExplorationPolicy folders in your colab and inside this folder you can find mars-explorer folder then make copy of the path of the mars-explorer folder for example. /content/GeneralExplorationPolicy/mars-explorer

then apply this command for install mars-explorer:

2. !pip install -e /content/GeneralExplorationPolicy/mars-explorer